# Android ListView getView display image randomly

Tags: java, android, listview, imageview, android-arrayadapter

I would like to display items with an adapter in a ListView but when getView is called in the ArrayAdapter, it displays the good image but not on the good item when I am scrolling. It is like if the findViewById didn't give me the good id of the layout.

```
public class ItemPackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pack> {
Context context;

public ItemPackAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Pack> pack) {
    super(context, 0, pack);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
    final Pack pack = getItem(position);
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_pack, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        if (!pack.getImageName().equals("null")) {
            UrlGenerator urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator();
            String url = urlGenerator.getDownloadPicture(pack.getImageName());
            DownloadPicture downloadPicture = new DownloadPicture(holder.imageView, url, getContext());
            downloadPicture.start();
        }
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else {
        holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView1.setText(pack.getSomething1());
    holder.textView2.setText(pack.getSomething2());
    holder.textView3.setText(pack.getSomething3());
    if (!pack.getImageName().equals("null")) {
        UrlGenerator urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator();
        String url = urlGenerator.getDownloadPicture(pack.getImageName());
        DownloadPicture downloadPicture = new DownloadPicture(holder.imageView, url, getContext());
        downloadPicture.start();
    }
    if(pack.getImageName().equals("null")){
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
    return convertView;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    TextView textView1;
    TextView textView2;
    TextView textView3;
    ImageView imageView;
}
}
```

Actually I found a solution with :

```
if(pack.getImageName().equals("null")){
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
    }
```

But when I am scrolling on the listView, I can see the image in the wrong item, and I need to scroll again to call getView to delete the image with the previous condition. 
I would like something cleaner :p

Thank you in advance.
And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: The issue is due to recycling of views. You may use `Picasso` or any other image loading library to avoid this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case if you don't caching your image that may give you like this problem. 
Use **Picasso** library is highly recommended for avoiding this problem. Add the **picasso** library in your project then write your code some thing like this.

```
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(url).into(holder.imageView);
```

instead of this line

```
DownloadPicture downloadPicture = new DownloadPicture(holder.imageView, url, getContext());
downloadPicture.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks will work just fine with just a little tweak. I discovered that you were setting the ImageView twice, so I edit your code as shown below

```
public class ItemPackAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Pack> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<Pack> packs;

    public ItemPackAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Pack> packs) {
        super(context, 0, packs);
        this.context = context;
        this.packs = packs;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
        final Pack pack = packs.get(position);
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_pack, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.textView3 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
            holder.imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if (pack.getImageName().equals("null")) {
            holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(null);
        } else {
            UrlGenerator urlGenerator = new UrlGenerator();
            String url = urlGenerator.getDownloadPicture(pack.getImageName());
            DownloadPicture downloadPicture = new DownloadPicture(holder.imageView, url, getContext());
            downloadPicture.start();
        }
        holder.textView1.setText(pack.getSomething1());
        holder.textView2.setText(pack.getSomething2());
        holder.textView3.setText(pack.getSomething3());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView textView1;
        TextView textView2;
        TextView textView3;
        ImageView imageView;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added the Picasso library and changed my code like you did, and know it works properly, thank you.